# NullPointerException when uploading a file .xlsx

Tags: java, oracle-adf

Such a problem, I follow the instructions from

http://www.awasthiashish.com/2017/01/import-data-from-xls-and-xlsx-excel-to.html

On the line throws NullPointerException

```
CollectionModel cModel = (CollectionModel) empTable.getValue();
```

I don't understand what to do, please help me!

jsff file:

```
<af:inputFile label="Select File" id="if1"                                   
valueChangeListener="#{pageFlowScope.Class1Bean.uploadFileVCE}"
autoSubmit="true" 
labelStyle="font-weight:bold;color:navy;"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to create the component binding for the table to the bean where you read the data.
In the page holding the table, select the table and add the component binding in the binding property.

Sample [enter link description here](https://fortunefusionminds.blogspot.com/2014/03/how-to-bind-ui-component-to-backing-bean.html)